# Vyatta DNAT not receiving and translating response back to private server

Tags: networking, routes, ip, nat, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

After setting up my Vyatta router, everything works correctly for communication between my servers on separate VLAN's. When I attempt to add access to the external internet with bidirectional NAT rules, I am unable to ping anything besides my internal servers. My SNAT rule correctly translates from the private server's IP to Vyatta's public IP.

```
source {
 rule 10 {
     log enable
     outbound-interface bond1
     source {
         address 10.x.x.x/26 (subnet of my private server)
     }
     translation {
         address 169.y.y.y (Vyatta public IP)
     }
  }
}
```

Correctly results in this on a `ping google.com` generated from my private server:

```
Pre-NAT           Post-NAT             Prot  Timeout 
10.x.x.x          169.y.y.y            icmp  29
```

However, my DNAT rule isn't receiving the response to `169.y.y.y` and translating it to `10.x.x.x` as it should, it only shows google's IP as the destination when coming back to Vyatta (...very odd). when using Wireshark, I can see the response is actually going to `169.y.y.y`, and should be correctly translated using my DNAT rule below.

```
destination {
  rule 10 {
     destination {
         address 169.y.y.y (Vyatta public IP)
     }
     inbound-interface bond1
     log enable
     translation {
         address 10.x.x.x (private server ip)
     }
  }
}

Pre-NAT                           Post-NAT             Prot  Timeout 
216.58.194.110 (google's IP??)    216.58.194.110       icmp  29
```

I've checked all my firewalls for dropped packets during this ping, but none are dropping any.

I'm new to Vyatta but this should be relatively straight forward, but is causing many issues for me. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this was that we were using zone-policy firewalls and hadn't made a zone for OUTSIDE that was configured on our public interface of the router. This full setup guide we found was extremely useful:

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/content/brocade-vrouter-vyatta-set-guide-vmware-environments-endurance-or-performance-storage